# Infinite recursion in python code for factorial using a dict.get() method

Tags: python, dictionary, factorial, infinite-recursion

I wrote a Python function to compute factorial of a number, like so;

```
def fact(n):
    return {0: 1}.get(n, n * fact(n-1))
```

I was surprised to see that it leads to infinite recursion, even for `fact(0)`. Then I added an assertion, like so;

```
def fact(n):
    assert n >= 0
    return {0: 1}.get(n, n * fact(n-1))
```

But this time AssertionError is raised, meaning `n` becomes negative. I don't understand this. I looked this up on the internet. But, unfortunately couldn't find any answer. Please can someone explain to me what's happening here?

Comment: `n * fact(n - 1)` needs to be evaluated *whether or not* n is in the dictionary, because it's an argument to get.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: All the parameters to get (or any other function or method) need to be evaluated *before* it's called. Think of it like `default = n * fact(n-1); return {0: 1}.get(n, default)`. Now is it obvious that line is never reached?

Comment: I get it now. So the call `fact(0)` evaluates to `{0: 1}.get(0, fact(-1))` and that makes it fail the assertion... Thank you @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 3):

In Python, function calls use 'eager' evaluation -- values are computed before a function is called, as opposed to computing them when a function actually uses them.

Thus, in

```py
    {0: 1}.get(n, n * fact(n-1))
```

The expression `n * fact(n-1)` is evaluated *before* even calling `get()`. I.e. the expression is evaluated even if get() doesn't need the value at all. This is what triggers the recursion.

Comment: Aha! So, the value of expression (n * fact(n-1) must be known in advance on the first call to the function? I get it now. Thanks for the very clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

`dict.get(item, default=None)` is just a function taking 1 or optionally two arguments. If you pass `n * fact(n-1)` as the default, that expression is evaluated before being passed. The whole

```
return {0: 1}.get(n, n * fact(n-1))
```

construct seems a little artificial. The simpler

```
return n * fact(n-1) if n else 1
```

is just as concise and will evaluate the respective expressions only when their logical branch is actually entered.

Comment: You're correct. But I just wanted to use a dictionary to branch rather than a control structure. Actually, that was my intention in the first place. Thanks.